# Parsing to Free Monads

Tags: haskell, monads, string-parsing, free-monad

Say I have the following free monad:

```
data ExampleF a
  = Foo Int a
  | Bar String (Int -> a)
  deriving Functor

type Example = Free ExampleF  -- this is the free monad want to discuss
```

I know how I  can work with this monad, eg. I could write some nice helpers:

```
foo :: Int -> Example ()
foo i = liftF $ Foo i ()

bar :: String -> Example Int
bar s = liftF $ Bar s id
```

So I can write programs in haskell like:

```
fooThenBar :: Example Int
fooThenBar =
  do
    foo 10
    bar "nice"
```

I know how to print it, interpret it, etc. But what about parsing it?

Would it be possible to write a parser that could parse arbitrary
programs like:

```
foo 12
bar nice
foo 11
foo 42
```

So I can store them, serialize them, use them in cli programs etc.

The problem I keep running into is that the type of the program depends on which program is being parsed. If the program ends with a `foo` it's of
type `Example ()` if it ends with a `bar` it's of type `Example Int`.

I do not feel like writing parsers for every possible permutation (it's simple here because there are only two possibilities, but imagine we add
`Baz Int (String -> a)`, `Doo (Int -> a)`, `Moz Int a`, `Foz String a`, .... This get's tedious and error-prone).

Perhaps I'm solving the wrong problem?

#### Boilerplate

To run the above examples, you need to add this to the beginning of the file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.Free
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
```

*Note: I put up [a gist containing this code](https://gist.github.com/4402caeedad10ff56e90).*

Comment: best to upload a fully working example to e.g. http://lpaste.net or for multiple files https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Suppose you can write a parser that returns `forall a. Example a`. What would you do with the result?

Comment: @n.m. It's to be used in a TCP interaction. The client sends commands and the server responds to them. Your question makes me feel I'm not totally getting it though ・‿・ Perhaps I should parse to an `Example Response` or something like `Response a => Example a`?

Comment: Ok so you want `Example Response`. That's much easier. What happens if the string actually parses to `Example Int`? A parse error. Your parser should be able to handle errors, shouldn't it?

Comment: Ok but then the last argument for every constructor of `ExampleF` has to be `(Response -> a)` right. This loses a lot of the expressivity of the `Example` monad. It feels more like a type-free language then, with `Response` just soaking up every possible type... Hmm have to think this through.

Comment: You are essentially expecting your parser to also do typechecking for you - your example expression is valid at one type `Example ()` but not at `Example Int` - therefore, if you have a parser of type `forall a . Parser (Example a)` then this parser must discriminate based on type, but it clearly does not (being parametric in `a`). So you need a function like `TypeWitness a -> Parser (Example a)`, where `TypeWitness` is a GADT indexed on your type language - or you just write one parser function for each type, the simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every `Example` value can be represented on the page without reimplementing some portion of Haskell. For example, `return putStrLn` has a type of `Example (String -> IO ())`, but I don't think it makes sense to attempt to parse that sort of `Example` value out of a file.

So let's restrict ourselves to parsing the examples you've given, which consist only of calls to `foo` and `bar` sequenced with `>>` (that is, no variable bindings and no arbitrary computations)*. The Backus-Naur form for our grammar looks approximately like this:

```
<program> ::= "" | <expr> "\n" <program>
<expr> ::= "foo " <integer> | "bar " <string>
```

It's straightforward enough to parse our two types of expression...

```
type Parser = Parsec String ()

int :: Parser Int
int = fmap read (many1 digit)

parseFoo :: Parser (Example ())
parseFoo = string "foo " *> fmap foo int

parseBar :: Parser (Example Int)
parseBar = string "bar " *> fmap bar (many1 alphaNum)
```

... but how can we give a type to the composition of these two parsers?

```
parseExpr :: Parser (Example ???)
parseExpr = parseFoo <|> parseBar
```

`parseFoo` and `parseBar` have different types, so we can't compose them with `<|> :: Alternative f => f a -> f a -> f a`. Moreover, there's no way to know ahead of time which type the program we're given will be: as you point out, the *type* of the parsed program depends on the *value* of the input string. "Types depending on values" is called *dependent types*; Haskell doesn't feature a proper dependent type system, but it comes close enough for us to have a stab at making this example work.

---

Let's start by forcing the expressions on either side of `<|>` to have the same type. This involves erasing `Example`'s type parameter using [*existential quantification*](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#existential-quantification).†

```
data Ex a = forall i. Wrap (a i)

parseExpr :: Parser (Ex Example)
parseExpr = fmap Wrap parseFoo <|> fmap Wrap parseBar
```

This typechecks, but the parser now returns an `Example` containing a value of an unknown type. A value of unknown type is of course useless - but we do know *something* about `Example`'s parameter: it must be either `()` or `Int` because those are the return types of `parseFoo` and `parseBar`. Programming is about getting knowledge out of your brain and onto the page, so we're going to wrap up the `Example` value with a bit of [GADT](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt) evidence which, when unwrapped, will tell you whether `a` was `Int` or `()`.

```
data Ty a where
    IntTy :: Ty Int
    UnitTy :: Ty ()

data (a :*: b) i = a i :&: b i

type Sig a b = Ex (a :*: b)
pattern Sig x y = Wrap (x :&: y)

parseExpr :: Parser (Sig Ty Example)
parseExpr = fmap (\x -> Sig UnitTy x) parseFoo <|>
            fmap (\x -> Sig IntTy x) parseBar
```

`Ty` is (something like) a runtime "singleton" representative of `Example`'s type parameter. When you pattern match on `IntTy`, you learn that `a ~ Int`; when you pattern match on `UnitTy` you learn that `a ~ ()`. (Information can be made to flow the other way, from types to values, using classes.) `:*:`, the [functor product](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html), pairs up two type constructors ensuring that their parameters are equal; thus, pattern matching on the `Ty` tells you about its accompanying `Example`.

`Sig` is therefore called a *dependent pair* or *sigma* type - the *type* of the second component of the pair depends on the *value* of the first. This is a common technique: when you erase a type parameter by existential quantification, it usually pays to make it recoverable by bundling up a runtime representative of that parameter.

Note that this use of `Sig` is equivalent to `Either (Example Int) (Example ())` - [a sigma type is a sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542350/dependent-types-how-is-the-dependent-pair-type-analogous-to-a-disjoint-union), after all - but this version scales better when you're summing over a large (or possibly infinite) set.

Now it's easy to build our expression parser into a program parser. We just have to repeatedly apply the expression parser, and then manipulate the dependent pairs in the list.

```
parseProgram :: Parser (Sig Ty Example)
parseProgram = fmap (foldr1 combine) $ parseExpr `sepBy1` (char '\n')
    where combine (Sig _ val) (Sig ty acc) = Sig ty (val >> acc)
```

The code I've shown you is not exemplary. It doesn't separate the concerns of parsing and typechecking. In production code I would modularise this design by first parsing the data into an untyped syntax tree - a separate data type which doesn't enforce the typing invariant - then transform that into a typed version by type-checking it. The dependent pair technique would still be necessary to give a type to the output of the type-checker, but it wouldn't be tangled up in the parser.

<sub>*If binding is not a requirement, have you thought about using a [free applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/Control-Applicative-Free.html) to represent your data?</sub>

<sub>†`Ex` and `:*:` are reusable bits of machinery which I lifted from the [Hasochism paper](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf)</sub>

Comment: nice answer! You're probably right that I just need a Free Applicative instead. I'm still quite new to the type Zoo so it's hard to find my way. More particular. I just need to be able to write simple embedded programs, and I wanted to partly capture their semantics (what command may return what value) in a nice way, so I stumbled on Free monads, which seem to be all the hype. Perhaps more people should write nice articles and blogposts on Free applicative too!

Comment: To be honest, I just tried to use Free Monads because of [this post](http://degoes.net/articles/modern-fp/). It's hard to see if Free Applicatives give me the same advantages as the article claims for Free Applicatives (mainly having multiple independent interpreters that are composable).

Comment: If all you need is `Applicative` then that's what you should use. Every `Monad` is an `Applicative` but not every `Applicative` is a `Monad`; the difference is that `Monad` allows future computations to depend on past results (whereas `Applicative` effects are purely static). `Applicative`s are easier to compose than `Monad`s, not harder.

Comment: Did you know that type operators don't need to start with colon anymore?  It makes code like this extra great.

Answer (score 2):

So, I worry that this is the same sort of premature abstraction that you see in object-oriented languages, getting in the way of things. For example, I am not 100% sure that you are using the structure of the free monad -- your helpers for example simply seem to use `id` and `()` in a rather boring way, in fact I'm not sure if your `Int -> x` is ever anything other than either `Pure :: Int -> Free ExampleF Int` or `const (something :: Free ExampleF Int)`.

The free monad for a functor F can basically be described as a tree whose data is stored in leaves and whose branching factor is controlled by the recursion in each constructor of the functor F. So for example `Free Identity` has no branching, hence only one leaf, and thus has the same structure as the monad:

```hs
data MonoidalFree m x = MF m x deriving (Functor)
instance Monoid m => Monad (MonoidalFree m) where
    return x = MF mempty x
    MF m x >>= my_x = case my_x x of MF n y -> MF (mappend m n) y
```

In fact `Free Identity` is isomorphic to `MonoidalFree (Sum Integer)`, the difference is just that instead of `MF (Sum 3) "Hello"` you see `Free . Identity . Free . Identity . Free . Identity $ Pure "Hello"` as the means of tracking this integer. On the other hand if you have `data E x = L x | R x deriving (Functor)` then you get a sort of "path" of Ls and Rs before you hit this one leaf, `Free E` is going to be isomorphic to `MonoidalFree [Bool]`.

The reason I'm going through this is that when you combine `Free` with an `Integer -> x` functor, you get an *infinitely branching tree*, and when I'm looking through your code to figure out how you're **actually using** this tree, all I see is that you use the `id` function with it. As far as I can tell, that restricts the recursion to either have the form `Free (Bar "string" Pure)` or else `Free (Bar "string" (const subExpression)),` in which case the system would seem to reduce completely to the `MonoidalFree [Either Int String]` monad.

(At this point I should pause to ask: Is that correct as far as you know? Was this what was intended?)

Anyway. Aside from my problems with your premature abstraction, the specific problem that you're citing with your monad (you can't tell the difference between `()` and `Int` has a bunch of really complicated solutions, but one really easy one. The really easy solution is to yield a value of type `Example (Either () Int)` and if you have a `()` you can `fmap Left` onto it and if you have an `Int` you can `fmap Right` onto it.

Without a much better understanding of **how** you're using this thing over TCP/IP we can't recommend a better structure for you than the generic free monads that you seem to be finding -- in particular we'd need to know how you're planning on using the infinite-branching of `Int -> x` options in practice.

Comment: Wow, this is a long answer. Thanks! I'll go trough it tonight when I have the time.